# Shower drain not level, water collects to one side of it. How can I level it without having to reinstall it?

Tags: shower, drain, level

I have a shower with ceramic tiles and a long stainless steel drain. The geniuses that installed it did not level it. The result is that water collects on one side of it. The collected water depth at the far side is about 3 mm or 1/8 inch; it does not overflow the drain.

Reinstalling the drain is not minor work so I would like to avoid it.

I thought of just putting some silicone caulk in there and leveling it manually but it doesn't sound like a clean job.

Is there a product I can put in there and level easily or a product that self-levels that I can pour in there?

Also, if the collected water remains there, can it possibly cause problems long-term?

[image]

Comment: As long as the water renews constantly it shouldn't be a problem. But if you go on a long vacation you might find it smelling wrong. Also I think some liquid glue would naturally level it, but I don't know what type could actually glue to that plastic and be liquid enough to go naturally to the side

Comment: I suppose you could try something like floor leveling compound (assuming it's water-resistant) or even some watery mix of mortar here.  But the correct solution is to remove and re-install this properly.

Comment: A thin epoxy, poured slowly and carefully, so as to ensure that you don't overflow into the drain (and permanently plug it), would level it. However, you _really_ want it to be sloped toward the drain, not just level.

Comment: Would it be practical to simply use a squeegee to get most of the water into the drain and then let the rest evaporate?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  Maybe you can get Mr. Mouse to stop by and drink the water.. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd definitely stay away from trying to reinstall it. If it's not leaking, don't tempt fate. 1/8" of water in the drain pan would evaporate fairly fast so it wouldn't cause any long term problems assuming regular shower cleaning.

If you're dead set on fixing it, a clear epoxy would be my best guess. It's self leveling and would form a water tight bond between it and the drain.

Comment: Jinx! Extra care should be taken if pouring epoxy into the drain trough - too much and it will flow down the drain causing a permanent clog (or at least a reduction in flow volume). Also, speed of evaporation is dependent on where in the world OP is. Some places are fairly humid and evaporation is _sloooow_

Comment: +1 for "do nothing".  Let it evaporate.   With any luck the evaporation will leave mineral deposits that will eventually self level. That may take a few hundred years though. :).  Remember there is always standing water inside the trap ... the part was designed to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just ignore this, use the shower, and see if anything untoward develops. But if I felt I had to do *something* my first thought would be a squeege after the last shower. I'd use a silicone spatula.

But that would require lifting the grill/cover and that does not comport with the ideals of gracious living.

So consider pouring a tablespoon of some liquid onto the grill at the far low end.  There are liquids which promote evaporation of water, e.g., rubbing alcohol, either denatured ethyl alcohol or isopropyl alcohol. You could keep a bottle of one of these in the shower alongside shampoo, etc., and pour *a small amount* in the far low end of the trough after the last shower of the morning or night showering.

You would want to calculate how much to add so you did not habitually add an excess. Excess is not desirable because some, presumably most, of this added organic solvent would end up in the air inside the house. Some would be evacuated by the bathroom exhaust fan, especially if it is on a timer so it stays on for 15 or 30 min after a shower.